Why is withOpacity deprecated in Flutter 3.27.0, and what is its recommended replacement?
I'm upgrading my Flutter project to version 3.27.0, and I noticed that the withOpacity method is marked as deprecated. I'm using it in my code as follows:
  SizedBox(
  height: 55,
  width: 50,
  child: VerticalDivider(
    color: const Color(0xff171433).withOpacity(0.1),
    thickness: 1.5,
  ),
)

This code works fine in earlier versions of Flutter, but after the upgrade, I receive a warning that withOpacity is deprecated.
I reviewed the Flutter changelog for 3.27.0 but couldn't find detailed information about why this change was made.
Questions:
Why was withOpacity deprecated in Flutter 3.27.0?
What is the recommended alternative or best practice to achieve the same functionality?
I’d appreciate any insights into the reasoning behind this deprecation and how I can adapt my code for the new version.

The reason withOpactiy has been deprecated in flutter 3.27.0 is because according to the flutter docs: "Previously, Color had the concept of "opacity" which showed up in the methods opacity and withOpacity(). Opacity was introduced as a way to communicate with Color about its alpha channel with floating point values. Now that alpha is a floating-point value, opacity is redundant and opacity and withOpacity are deprecated and slated to be removed". The recommended replacement is using .withValues(), this would also help to avoid precision loss because of how its values still remain in their floating point representation.
How to use .withvalues() correctly while migrating from withOpacity():
// Before
final x = color.withOpacity(0.0);
// After
final x = color.withValues(alpha: 0.0);


perfect explanation

So, this is a known migration and was highlighted in the Flutter migration guide. The deprecation of withOpacity is part of a broader change aimed at improving Flutter’s color system, especially for wide-gamut colors.
Reason for deprecation
Previously, Color had the concept of “opacity,” represented by methods like .opacity and .withOpacity(). Opacity was introduced to allow interaction with the alpha channel using floating-point values. However, since alpha is now natively treated as a floating-point value, opacity is no longer necessary. As a result, opacity and withOpacity() are deprecated and will eventually be removed.
How to migrate withOpacity
Before:
final x = color.withOpacity(0.1);

After:
final x = color.withValues(alpha: 0.1);

The withValues method lets you specify the alpha value directly, aligning with the new color system’s approach to handling alpha.
How to migrate .opacity
Before:
This returned the alpha value as a floating-point number.
final x = color.opacity; 

After:
Now you can access the alpha channel directly.
final x = color.a;

For Your specific case in Question
To adapt your code, you can migrate it as follows:
Before:
SizedBox(
  height: 55,
  width: 50,
  child: VerticalDivider(
    color: const Color(0xff171433).withOpacity(0.1),
    thickness: 1.5,
  ),
)

After:
SizedBox(
  height: 55,
  width: 50,
  child: VerticalDivider(
    color: const Color(0xff171433).withValues(alpha: 0.1),
    thickness: 1.5,
  ),
)

This approach is fully compatible with Flutter ^3.27.0 and ensures you won’t encounter deprecation warnings.
If you’d like more details, check out the official migration guide by Flutter.

The withOpacity() method has been deprecated and is no longer recommended. It will soon be removed, if not already removed.
Deprecated Method:
const Color(0xff171433).withOpacity(0.1)

New Recommended Method:
const Color(0xff171433).withValues(alpha: 0.1)

The withValues() method is the updated way to adjust the alpha (opacity) of a color, ensuring better precision and compatibility with the latest Flutter versions.
NOTE
If, after updating to Flutter 3.27.0 or newer, your IDE doesn’t recognize withValues, you may need to run the following command in your project directory to resolve the issue:
flutter clean


Previously, Color had the concept of opacity which showed up in the methods opacity and withOpacity(). Opacity was introduced as a way to communicate with Color about its alpha channel with floating point values. Now that alpha is a floating-point value, opacity is redundant and opacity and withOpacity are deprecated and slated to be removed.

withOpacity migration

// Before
final x = color.withOpacity(0.0);
// After
final x = color.withValues(alpha: 0.0);

you can read more about migration here

Migrating older projects can sometimes be challenging, especially when dealing with deprecated methods and duplicate code. To address this, I wanted to solve both the deprecated opacity issue and reduce repetitive code like withAlpha((0.1 * 255).toInt()). Here's an extension on the Color class that resolves the opacity problem and handles deprecated issues efficiently:
extension ColorWithOpacityExt on Color {
 /// Extension on [Color] to resolve opacity based on a [double] value.
 /// The opacity is expected to be between 0.0 (fully transparent) and
/// 1.0 (fully opaque).
/// Returns a new color with the applied opacity.
Color resolveOpacity(double opacity) {
opacity = opacity.clamp(0.0, 1.0);
int alpha = (opacity * 255).round();
return withAlpha(alpha);
}
}

Usage -> background: Colors.black.resolveOpacity(0.40),
This way, you can easily handle opacity in a cleaner, more maintainable manner without repeating the conversion logic.

Use .withAlpha() with a value between 0 and 255 to represent the alpha channel directly.
eg: Color(0xff171433).withOpacity(0.1) -> Color(0xff171433).withAlpha((0.1 * 255).toInt())
